# How to suppress INFO messages when running psql scripts

Tags: postgresql, testing, logging

I'm seeing INFO messages when I run my tests and I *thought* that I had gotten rid of them by setting the client_min_messages PGOPTION.  Here's my command:

```
PGOPTIONS='--client-min-messages=warning' \
          psql  -h localhost \
                -p 5432 \
                -d my_db \
                -U my_user \
                --no-align \
                --field-separator '|' \
                --pset footer \
                --quiet \
                -v AUTOCOMMIT=off \
                -X \
                -v VERBOSITY=terse \
                -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 \
                --pset pager=off \
                -f tests/test.sql \
                -o "$test_results"
```

Can someone advise me on how to turn off the INFO messages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me: Postgres 9.1.4 on Debian GNU Linux with bash:

```
env PGOPTIONS='-c client_min_messages=WARNING' psql ...
```

(Still works for Postgres 12 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with bash.)

It's also what [the manual suggests](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html#id-1.6.6.4.5). In most shells, setting environment variables also works without an explicit leading `env`. See [maxschlepzig's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404206/how-to-suppress-info-messages-when-running-psql-scripts/11411109?noredirect=1#comment112979809_11411109).

Note, however, that there is no message level `INFO` for [`client_min_messages`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHEN).
That's only applicable to `log_min_messages` and `log_min_error_statement`.

Comment: FWIW, in bash/zsh/ksh  the `env` comand is superfluous - i.e. just putting the assignment in front of your psql command has the same effect.