# INFO output despite "SET client_min_messages TO WARNING" just before

Tags: postgresql, logging, session-variables, error-logging, postgresql-9.0

postgresql-9.0.15 on CentOS 6.5.  I have a plperlu function that outputs an INFO message.  I want to suppress it during testing (using psql, which also behaves as below), but I can't even seem to do it from a pgAdminIII (1.18.1 for win2003) query window:

```
SET client_min_messages TO WARNING;
select my_info_outputting_function('lalala')
```

I run that and look in the "messages" tab, and there's my INFO message.

(This may appear similar to [How to suppress INFO messages when running psql scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404206/how-to-suppress-info-messages-when-running-psql-scripts) , but I don't want to disable INFO messages for my whole session, just part of it and then set the minimum back to NOTICE.)

What am I doing wrong with the above code snippet?  Does client_min_messages not apply to pl/perlu functions?

UPDATE: upon further investigation, it seems to happen even with plpgsql functions, not just plperlu functions:

```
create or replace function my_info_outputting_function() returns void as $$
begin
    raise INFO 'this should not appear...';
    return;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
SET client_min_messages TO WARNING;
select my_info_outputting_function();
```

I run the above snippet in a pgAdminIII query window and "this should not appear" appears in the messages tab.  Quoi?

Update 2: I also tried [log_min_messages](http://bytes.com/topic/postgresql/answers/423022-supressing-notice-messages-windows-cygwin-only-not-working) just in case.  Same behaviour.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I asked on the postgresql-general mailing list and received [an informative answer](https://web.archive.org/web/20170807010400/https://www.postgresql-archive.org/client-min-messages-not-suppressing-messages-in-psql-nor-pgAdminIII-td5788089.html): what distinguishes `INFO` from `NOTICE` is that `INFO` does not have a level: it's intended to always go through, no matter what `client_min_messages` or anything else is set to, from functions that you would call specifically for INFO output.  So in my case, the appropriate thing is to output only `NOTICE` from my function.

Comment: Link dead. This is the thread, presumably: https://www.postgresql-archive.org/client-min-messages-not-suppressing-messages-in-psql-nor-pgAdminIII-td5788089.html

Comment: Please use an archiving service when you encounter bit rot: https://web.archive.org/web/20170807010400/https://www.postgresql-archive.org/client-min-messages-not-suppressing-messages-in-psql-nor-pgAdminIII-td5788089.html