# Reduce bothering notices in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, debugging, plpgsql, notice

I have a function which uses temporary table, that must be dropped if exists.

```
drop table if exists t_xy;
create temp table t_xy on commit drop as select ...;
```

Subsequently I use this function in a view. The function is called many times while select is in progress. I like to use "raise notice" command because it is almost the only reliable way to report any variables in functions for debug purposes. The problem is I must search for them in huge amount of unwanted lines like:

```
NOTICE:  table "t_xy" does not exist, skipping
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "drop table if exists t_xy"
PL/pgSQL function f_pending_operations(uuid) line5 in SQL command
```

Is there a way to suppress such notices that haven't been generated by `raise notice` command, but by `drop table if exists` or dropping other objects? Setting 'client_min_messages' option to 'debug' makes the problem worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can silence notices to the client from any command with a local setting for [`client_min_messages`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHEN):

```
SET LOCAL client_min_messages = warning;  -- "debug" would have opposite effect
DROP TABLE if exists t_xy;
-- RESET client_min_messages;
```

If you don't issue `RESET` you effectively silence notices for the rest of the transaction. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html)

> The effects of `SET LOCAL` last only till the end of the current transaction

Alternatively, you can set `client_min_messages` in the call from the command line (for the duration of the session):

- [How to suppress INFO messages when running psql scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404206/how-to-suppress-info-messages-when-running-psql-scripts/11411109#11411109)

Comment: That aside, chances are there are (much) **betters solutions** than creating temp tables for every call of a view. I suggest you start a new question with all details for your view. My first shot in the dark, would be CTEs ...

Comment: In fact I need the temporary table only for debugging purposes. I collected another data in it for subsequent print by plain select * from t_xy. So I can remove it in production mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can also reduce the verbosity of the messages using the GUC parameter:

`set log_error_verbosity='terse';`

which can of course be set at the function level.