# Script execution prints every "DO" from my script

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, psql

For a migration I have automatically built scripts containing anonymous blocks for every entity to update and keep a log table for the results.

```
DO $$
DECLARE productId varchar;
BEGIN
  productId := getProductId('9783980493017');
  update product set ...;
  ...
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  insert into mig_messages(createddate,identifier,message)
  values(now(), '9783980493017', SQLERRM);
END $$;
```

This works fine so far. But when I run these scripts with psql every `DO` is printed on the prompt. This sounds a bit silly, but there are lots of scripts with lots of product update blocks in it (about 5 millions or more). How can I suppress this output without redirecting it completely to /dev/null or switching psql to silent? At last there MAY be some output I want to see (errors, warnings etc.).

Comment: Does the `--quiet` parameter do what you want?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Does --quiet still print error messages? I would especially be interested in lost connections or other "hard" errors not generated by my script itself.

Comment: OK, it does; I have tried it out and it printed a syntax error. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prepend the script with this line:

```
SET client_min_messages=WARNING
```

Or start `psql` with that setting in the environment (I am using this in bash).

```
env PGOPTIONS='-c client_min_messages=WARNING' psql ...
```

This way you still get messages with severity WARNING or higher.
Related:

- [How to suppress INFO messages when running psql scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404206/how-to-suppress-info-messages-when-running-psql-scripts)
- [Reduce bothering notices in plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588613/reduce-bothering-notices-in-plpgsql/27605183?noredirect=1#comment44235667_27605183)