Could pg notice be discarded in NiFi?
My NiFi flow calls pg functions. For debugging purpose multiple raise-notice statements are embedded in pg functions. while handling huge dataset, they generate abundant text output for programmer. However, those texts output let NiFi processor be blocked too. In some cases, it even results in heap overflowing. So, if I want to keep raise-notice statements for a while during developing, it's good to see any switch or config for NiFi sql-executing processors for disabling or discarding notice message from pg.

I assume you've tried, or ruled out, setting client_min_messages like discussed in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39457/how-to-turn-off-all-raise-notice-on-production-server and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588613/reduce-bothering-notices-in-plpgsql

It's the answer if I steadily use one of the two: PgAdmin or NiFi. No switching is needed. You remaind me that I should debug NiFi flow after having written and well tested pg functions.
